# zencart getting async=true in html product page url, how to remove async=true

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, url

I am getting async=true in product page url of an zencart website.

Like this  dangling-c-1427_1431/np3d02-p-27633.html?async=true

Please tell me how to remove this from url.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please have look on 
http://jsfiddle.net/5LmLW/25/

```
var url = 'dangling-c-1427_1431/np3d02-p-27633.html?async=true'
alert(url.split('?')[0]);
```

Are you expecting like this?

Comment: Vinothini,

I am not looking to this way.
I wan to disable this setting from admin/template but didn't found same.

Thanks